# Webcam support broken in 19.10?

Tags: firefox, webcam

After installing Ubuntu 19.10 I can no longer use my webcam properly in Firefox:

- On [Jitsi Meet](https://meet.jit.si/) I get a browser warning saying I should try using one of the "fully supported browsers", which includes Firefox.
- Google Hangouts starts ringing, showing the webcam video in the background, and then pops up this message:

  > Sorry, we've encountered a problem with joining this video call.

I'm running the latest available version of Firefox, 72.0.1:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep firefox

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

firefox-locale-en/eoan-updates,eoan-security,now 72.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 amd64 [installed]
firefox/eoan-updates,eoan-security,now 72.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: Are you using the apt or snap version of firefox? Does the problem happen in other browsers and/or applications like cheese?

Comment: The problem does not happen in Chromium.

Comment: Then I can only suggest to check in preferences if the website can access the camera. You could maybe also try the snap version of firefox with `snap install firefox` and see if it works there.